# Inspect network traffic with Android Studio +3.3 using https

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, profiling

As the title said, with the new release of AS 3.3 I tried inspect network traffic but as you can see in the following screenshot, it's detecting the incoming/outgoing data but it can't understand what kind of data is it:
[image]

of course it can't, I'm using HTTPS with a *different https library* (smack for xmpp).

In the official [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler) you can read this:

> Currently, the Network Profiler supports only the HttpURLConnection and OkHttp libraries for network connections. If your app uses another network connection library, you may not be able to view your network activity in the Network Profiler.

So the question is:
is there **any way** to use this nice tool with HTTPS/TLS/certificates? or even better with socket connections?
When I said, "any way" it can be customize AS plugins or something like that. Any idea?

Comment: The fact that you are using https is irrelevant, I use it with SSL connections all the time and most of the time it works well, sometimes it fails but it's not because you're using https, though the reasons are not clear. I have been using it with both OkHttp and HttpUrlConnection, and I can say that the former works close to 100% of the time, while with apps using HttpUrlConnection it fails very often to get request/response bodies and things like that.

Comment: Seems like you are using the libraries that they support so far :), which is not my case. When I was dealing with that problem is was using a library call Smack (is for chat apps following XMPP protocol).

Comment: So adding to my point, the SSL layer was not your issue, using an incompatible library was... :)

Comment: got it, I edited the question to specify that I'm using a different library.